# div border is not working when set that div inside the svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg

here is my code,

```
<div class="content-container-fluid">      
    <div class="row">                
        <div class="cols-sample-area" style="width: 100%;"> 
            <div id="scrollcontent" style="width:92% !important; transform: translate(0, 50%);">                  
                <div id="scrollcontenttemplate_group_" style="position: absolute;">
                    <div id="scrollcontentthumbleft" style="position: absolute; top: 42px; cursor: pointer; z-index: 1; left: 276.34375px;">
                        <div style="width:8px;height:36px;background-color: #41d335;border: 1px solid black;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <svg id="scrollcontent_svg" style="overflow:visible;position:relative" height="120" width="1188">
                    <g id="scrollcontenthigherLevel" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <line x1="1" y1="0" x2="1" y2="21" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="1 1 10"></line>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Out put image]

line stroke dash array is applied to that div? how to resolve this?

why the border shown like this.. how to solve?

[Sample link](http://jsfiddle.net/3eXfk/176/)

Comment: your code working fine.. but can't understand your question.. "why border shown like this"..

Comment: Doesn't happen for me on Firefox. What are you using?

Comment: this issue reproduced only in chrome

Answer (score 1):

The SVG's dash array is not actually affecting the `<div>` .  It's just seems to be a weird rendering/compositing anomaly in Chrome.

You can confirm it is not the dasharray by changing the dasharray values.
Also if you zoom the page (Ctrl-+) the "dashing" goes away.

I have no idea what the cause is, but you may want to [report the bug to Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).